# Post Back To ASP.NET Boilerplate

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-boilerplate

NET Boilerplate Core project that redirects a user to an external payment gateway but when the gateway redirects back to the given url it redirects but i just get a screen that says cannot post. I don't know if someone has ran into this problem before and i cant seem to find a solution seeing that the the web site and service run independently.

Comment: Check your Logs.txt. I believe this is due to anti-forgery token.